# Como carregar apenas uma linha e modifica-la

Tags: python, arquivo

Eu quero modificar apenas uma linha de um arquivo, algo mais ou menos dessa forma

```
    with open('arquivo.txt', 'r+') as f:

    for line in f.readlines():
        if line == algumacoisa:
            line.write('textoaqui');
            break
    f.close()
```

Eu vi em outra pergunta que para fazer isso você deve carregar o arquivo inteiro, modificar ele, e salvar novamente, porem isso não é viável, por que o arquivo tem milhões de linhas, e eu não quero salvar todos os milhões de linhas cada vez que executar a função.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando o seguinte é possivel ler o arquivo por linhas. Assim que uma linha é lida,a antiga é descartada pelo garbage collector:

```
import os
with open('arquivo.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for linha in f:
        with open('arquivo-1.txt', 'a+') as f:
            if line == algumacoisa:
                f.write('textoaqui')

            else:
                f.write(linha)

            f.write('\n')

os.remove('arquivo.txt')
os.rename('arquivo-1.txt', 'arquivo.txt')
```

Comment: A unica diferença para oque eu quero é não pretendo escrever em outro arquivo.